# Get data to php via animated form?

Tags: javascript, php

So I have the following animated form in my HTML code.

```
<form id="formElem" name="formElem" action="" method="post">
                        <fieldset class="step">
                            <legend>Consultation</legend>
                            <p>
                                <input class = "consultation" type="submit" value="General Consultation">
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input class = "consultation" type="submit" value="Blood Test with Consultation">
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input class = "consultation" type="submit" value="Full Sexual Health Screen">
                            </p>
                             <p>
                                <input class = "consultation" type="submit" value="Hair Loss PRP Treatment">
                            </p>
                             <p>
                                <input class = "consultation" type="submit" value="Executive Health Screening">
                            </p>
                             <p>
                                <input class = "consultation" type="submit" value="Flu Vaccination">
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input class = "consultation" type="submit" value="Other">
                            </p>

                                <input type="hidden" name="consultation" id="consultation" value="">
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset class="step">
                            <legend>Provider</legend>
                             <p>
                                <input class = "provider" type="submit" value="Dr. Kevin O'Connell">
                            </p>
                             <p>
                                <input class = "provider" type="submit" value="Dr. Rachel Fitxgerald">
                            </p>
                             <p>
                                <input class = "provider" type="submit" value="Dr. Simon Gilmore">
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input class = "provider" type="submit" value="Nurse Julie Byrne">
                            </p>

                                <input type="hidden" name="provider" id="provider" value="">
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset class="step">
                            <legend>Date</legend>
                            <p>
                                <input type="date" name="date">
                            </p>
                             <p class="submit">
                                <button id="registerButton" type="submit">Confirm</button>
                            </p>
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset class="step">
                            <legend>Confirm</legend>
                            <p>
                                Thank you for requesting an appointment. We will be in touch with you shortly to confirm it.
                            </p>
                            <p class="submit">
                                <button id="registerButton"type="submit">Home</button>
                            </p>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

As you can see each element is a clickable one then it brings you to the next part of the form. My goal is to, when submitted, have each of the elements the user clicked on be sent to the action page via php and using $_POST. I have tried using jQuery for this and detecting when an element is clicked, transferring that value to a hidden input and retrieving the data from that but I can't seem to get it right.

```
$('input.consultation').click(function(){
  $(this).text() = consultation_value;
  $('#consultation').text() = consultation_value;
  console.log(consultation_value);
});

$('input.provider').click(function(){
  $(this).text() = provider_value;
  $('#provider').text() = provider_value;
  console.log(provider_value);
});
```

If anyone could help me learn why my code isn't working or offer a more efficient solution I'd appreciate it

Comment: the (or one) problem is, that you allways overwrite `$('#consultation').text()`. Does  `$('#consultation').text() = $('#consultation').text() + consultation_value;` give you what you need?

Comment: _but_ where is 'consultation_value` set for this line: `$(this).text() = consultation_value;` ?

Comment: @Jeff I just have that as the name of a variable, so whatever text the user clicks on goes into the variable "consultation_value"

Comment: After 3 more looks at the code I don't think this is the right path for what you are trying to achieve. It looks to me like taken html snippets from a wizard library without using that js library. I suppose it's an "XY Problem".

Comment: @Jeff do you have an advised alternate method? I'd really appreciate it

Comment: First you'd have to say what all this shall really do. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Jeff Well there are 3 parts to the form, select a consultation, provider and date. The user will pick one of each. I would like for the 3 things they chose to be inputted into a my sql database. But right now I'm struggling to acquire the users choices via $_POST